# Chaquopy in Android Studio module not found

Tags: java, android, python, chaquopy

I have implemented Chaquopy into my Android app to make use of pre-trained Neural Network models in python.

Trying to call the python code, I am encountering;

"com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataLoader'

I am unsure if I have wrongly implemented the file structure for Chaquopy or if there is another reason it cannot import the DataLoader module.

DataLoader.py is in the same location as main.py, inside app/src/main/python/SimpleHRT/  so I don't see why it cannot access the module.

From the Android app to call the python;

```
convertImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (! Python.isStarted()){
                    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getActivity()));
                }
                else{
                    Python py = Python.getInstance();
                    PyObject test = py.getModule("SimpleHRT/main");
                }
            }
        });
```

From the python main.py

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import argparse
import cv2
import editdistance
from DataLoader import DataLoader, Batch
from Model import Model, DecoderType
from SamplePreprocessor import preprocess
```

From the Error log

```
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teesside.yellowann, PID: 5735
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DataLoader'
        at <python>.java.chaquopy.import_override(import.pxi:18)
        at <python>.java._vendor.six.reraise(six.py:686)
        at <python>.java.chaquopy.import_override(import.pxi:59)
        at <python>.SimpleHRT/main.<module>(main.py:8)
        at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module_impl(importer.py:435)
        at <python>.java.android.importer.load_module(importer.py:353)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_backward_compatible(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:626)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:656)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load_unlocked(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:955)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._find_and_load(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:971)
        at <python>.importlib._bootstrap._gcd_import(<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:994)
        at <python>.importlib.import_module(__init__.py:126)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_Python_getModule(chaquopy_java.pyx:154)
        at com.chaquo.python.Python.getModule(Native Method)
        at com.teesside.yellowann.ImageFragment$3.onClick(ImageFragment.java:173)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5735 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

EDIT
Continuation:

Didn't want to raise a brand new question when this is pretty much the same thing.

Trying to now implement:

Android Java call

```
convertImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (! Python.isStarted()){
                    Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getActivity()));
                }
                else{
                    Python py = Python.getInstance();
                    PyObject test = py.getModule("SimpleHRT.main").get("main");
                    PyObject test2 = test.call();
                }
            }
        });
```

Python Filepaths

```
class FilePaths:
    "filenames and paths to data"
    fnCharList = '../model/charList.txt'
    fnAccuracy = '../model/accuracy.txt'
    fnTrain = '../data/'
    fnInfer = '../data/test.png'
    fnCorpus = '../data/corpus.txt'
```

Python call

```
model = Model(open(FilePaths.fnCharList).read(), decoderType, mustRestore=True)
infer(model, FilePaths.fnInfer)
```

Error log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.teesside.yellowann, PID: 9330
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SimpleHRT/../model/charList.txt'
        at <python>.SimpleHRT.main.main(main.py:138)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:283)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callThrows(chaquopy_java.pyx:243)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callThrows(Native Method)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.call(PyObject.java:190)
        at com.teesside.yellowann.ImageFragment$3.onClick(ImageFragment.java:176)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9330 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

I have tried "./model/charList.txt", "SimpleHRT/model/charList.txt", "SimpleHRT/../model/charList.txt", ".../model/charList.txt", "./../model/charList.txt"

The base python is in "src/main/python/SimpleHRT/" whereas the documents I need to read from are in "src/main/python/SimpleHRT/model/"

I'm assuming there's just some nuance about the file-pathing that I'm not grasping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do an implicit relative import. This would work in Python 2, but Python 3 requires you to explcitly indicate when you're loading a module from the same package.

So instead of `from DataLoader`, you'll need to use `from .DataLoader` or `from SimpleHRT.DataLoader`.

Alternatively, you could move all the code to the top-level `src/main/python` directory, and then the import statements would work without any change.

(This may not be related, but you should also use Python module name syntax when callling `getModule`, i.e. `SimpleHRT.main`, not `SimpleHRT/main`. Actually, I'm surprised the second one worked at all.)

**EDIT** for second part of question: To load resource files packaged alongside your code, see https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#resource-files.

Comment: Thank you, the code compiles again and returns "<module 'SimpleHRT.main' from '/android_asset/chaquopy/app.zip/SimpleHRT/main.py'>". Now onto the next part!

Comment: Please read the edit I've made. I've spent all day trying to get the python to run but I think there's something simple I'm missing. I considered moving all the files to the src/main/python directory, but there's going to be almost 40 files in total - without proper pathing it's going to end up as a confusing incomprehensible mess...

Comment: @GoddessAphrael: I've added a link to the documentation which should help you.